# Return List of either ApplicationUser objects or ApplicationUserId strings

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a Twitter-style followers/following setup in my ASP.NET Core project.

I am trying to build a LINQ query that will return records that belong to me and to the network of users that I 'follow'.  Something like this:

```
.Where(o => usersFollowingList.Contains(o.ApplicationUser.Id))
```

My followers/following setup is a self-referencing relationship with .NET Core's IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Network> Following { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Network> Followers { get; set; }
}

public class Network
{
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Follower { get; set; }
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }
}
```

This setup gives me a list of users I am **Following**.  The collection has the ApplicationUser object and their ApplicationUserId which is string type.

I am hitting a problem trying to get a collection of either ApplicationUser objects or ApplicationUserId strings that I can use in my WHERE clause above.

I can get a list of my followers' ApplicationUserId strings like this:

```
var g = from p in loggedinUser.Following
select p.ApplicationUser.Id.ToString();
```

But this does not contain my own ApplicationUserId.  And I cannot easily add my own ApplicationUserId to this collection because it is an IEnumerable type.

How can I get an appropriate collection of either ApplicationUser objects or ApplicationUserId strings that I can use in my WHERE clause?  Or is there a better way to use the Followers list in my WHERE filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Concat` to add two `IEnumerable`, so you just need to convert yourself to a singleton `IEnumerable`. I prefer an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> rest, params T[] last) => rest.Concat(last);
```

Now you can query as:

```
var g = (from p in loggedinUser.Following
         select p.ApplicationUser.Id.ToString())
        .Append(loggedinUser.Id.ToString());
```

But why use `g` in the `Where` if you already have the `Following` `Network` objects?

```
var g = loggedinUser.Following
                    .Append(loggedinUser);
```

Of course, you could also do the `Where` but that is unnecessary searching:

```
.Where(o => usersFollowingList.Contains(o.ApplicationUser.Id) || o.ApplicationUser.Id == loggedinUser.Id)
```

Comment: Thank you @NetMage.  I will mark as 'answered.  Just wanted to follow up on your line: "But why use g in the Where if you already have the Following Network objects?".  How can I use Following Network object?  The WHERE needs either an ApplicationUser or the Id.  I can't seem to get the query to use the information from the Network object.  Any ideas? :)

Comment: 'Following' is of type ''Network'.  But I need type ApplicationUser in the query.

Comment: My question is why do you need to a query at all; why use `Where` when `Following` already contains the network objects your `Where` appears to be returning?